# fullpage.js having some sections scrollable

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I can't figure if there is any way to do this, but can I/how do I make a site where you section-scroll through 2 sections, and then enable normal navigation in the 3rd section. I basically want to make a site that works like this

```
Front page with introduction
  |
Portal selection(select 1 of 3 games)
  |
List of blog posts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the option `scrollOverflow` for it, as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).